# How do I remove a charge-off from my credit score?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, credit-report, credit-history

I currently have a credit score of 667.  The only negative note I have is from a credit card where I owed $4,100 but failed to make any payments for 22 months.  That debt was eventually charged-off.  However, in June 2016 I paid the debt off in full in one lump sum and then closed that credit card.

Will this affect my credit score for the next 7 years or is there a way I can have this taken off my credit report sooner?

Comment: Did you pay the credit card company or a collection agency?  You might want to call them and ask them very nicely if they would consider taking it off.  This should have been something you negotiated when arranging for settlement.  You will probably have more success with a CC company.

Comment: @PeteB. For my own curiosity, how long does a CC company hold onto debt before selling it?

Comment: I don't know and I am pretty sure iv varies from company to company.

Comment: @PeteB. I paid off to the credit card directly in full.  It almost seems like I should have spoken with the CC company before paying it off.  That way I could have asked them to not put a negative note on my credit history.  Now that it's paid off, do you think the CC company might still take it off my report if I ask nicely?  Thanks for your input on this.

Comment: @Sprinkles  It can't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to remove that debt collection from your credit report. It will stay on there for at most 7 years **from the first date of delinquency.** You could try and [dispute](https://www.thebalance.com/remove-debt-collections-from-your-credit-report-960376) it.

> However, if you can't remove the debt by disputing it, you can
>   negotiate with the collector to have the account removed from your
>   credit report in exchange for payment.

It will have an impact on your credit score, but over time, your score should go up if you continue to stay current on all your debts, not opening new lines of credit unless you need to, don't utilize more than 30% of the credit available to you, etc.